# Удалит ли деструктор по умолчанию объект, хранящийся в классе в виде ссылки?

Tags: c++

Если поле класса хранит ссылку на объект, удалит ли деструктор по умолчанию объект, на который ссылается поле?

Comment: Не обязательно. На объект может ссылаться и другой класс.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, ведь ссылка не обязательно указывает на объект, созданный `new`.

Деструктор по умолчанию только вызывает деструкторы всех полей и базовых классов, если они есть.

Answer (score 1):

Деструктор вызывается при смерти обьекта. Если обьект `А` хранит ссыльку на  обьект `В`, то при уничтожении обьекта `А`  вызовится его деструктор, который не обязательно должен уничтожать объект `В`(деструктор по умолчанию точно это не сделает), если только вы так не захотите(часто это плохая идея). А если объект `В` не находится в динамической памяти, то никакой деструктор не сможет его уничтожать. P.S. Тут главное заботится о том, чтобы обьект  `В` не был удален раньше чем `А` станет не нужным.